# Tosca not edifying field in FIORI test automation

Tags: automation, automated-tests, tosca

I'm currently using Tosca to automate a specific SAP process in FIORI. At the end of the process, I need to click a specific field to finish the process.

What happens is that the program doesn't recognize the field. I tried multiple scans and rescans and nothing worked.

Any advice to overcome the situation?

Please see screenshots.

[image]

[image]
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find RadioButton inside the DIV in XScan.
It is better to use set value True/False (if possible) than to click on the element.